# UaException: status=Bad_SessionClosed, message=The session was closed by the client

Tags: java, opc-ua, opc, milo

Something happened when I used Milo,I do not know why it happened:

> UaException: status=Bad_SessionClosed, message=The session was closed
> by the client.    at
> org.eclipse.milo.opcua.sdk.client.session.SessionFsmFactory.lambda$null$1(SessionFsmFactory.java:159)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you’re trying to get the Session but nothing has called `SessionFsm::openSession`. You’ll have to share some code, because this is normally done by the SDK if you are using `OpcUaClient`.

Did you call `OpcUaClient::connect` before using it?